# Magento invalid block type

Tags: magento

I wanted to build Custom Input Fields in Magentos Product/Custom Option Area.  I started to write a new Module.
In "etc/modules" i created "Pi_Customize.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pi_Customize>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pi_Customize>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in "app/code/local/etc" I created the "config.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pi_Customize>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Pi_Customize>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <options>
                    <custom>
                        <groups>
                            <custom translate="label" module="customize">
                                <label>Custom Stuff</label>
                                <render>customize/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_custom</render>
                                <types>
                                    <custom_type translate="label" module="customize">
                                        <label>Custom Text</label>
                                    </custom_type>
                                </types>
                            </custom>
                        </groups>
                    </custom>
                </options>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

when i reload in backend/product/custom options i see the new added field, but i get an error:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Customize_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_custom' in /home/michi/www/magento/app/Mage.php:595
```

I am trying around about 4 hours, and can't get it tor work. Why is Magento trying to load "mage" instead of "pi/customize".  How should the folder Structure then look like?
A: "Adminhtml/block/catalog....."
B: "Block/catalog..."
C: another?

Answer (score 2):

Your post lacks some context, and it's unclear what you think the above should do, so that makes it hard to completely address your question.

That said, your configuration indicated you want to use the following block class as a render

```
<render>customize/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_custom</render>
```

This means Magento will attempt to instantiate the a `customize/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_custom` block class.  There is not a `customize` block namespace in a stock Magento system, and you haven't added one via your configuration.  That means `customize/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_custom` corresponds to the PHP class

```
Mage_Customize_Helper_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Custom
```

This class doesn't exist in Magento, and you get the error you get.

Although your error is curious as well.  The lower case custom (`Options_Type_custom`) makes is seem like there's other things going on you haven't mentioned in your question.

Comment: the same error happened to me also. Magento is taking the tabs also as part of class name. When I removed the tabs it worked fine. The error was: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: 
                        Kaushikamdotcom_Pay_Block_History
                    ' in /var/www/kaushikam/magento/app/Mage.php:595

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, i changed my config.xml, like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pi_Customize>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Pi_Customize>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                        Pi_Customize_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
                    </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <customize>
                <class>Pi_Customize_Block</class>
            </customize>
        </blocks>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <options>
                    <custom>
                        <groups>
                            <customize translate="label" module="customize">
                                <label>Customized Input</label>
                                <render>customize/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_customized</render>
                                <types>
                                    <customize_type translate="label" module="customize">
                                        <label>custom</label>
                                    </customize_type>
                                    <!-- the second one
                                    <customizedue_type translate="label" module="customize">
                                        <label>due</label>
                                    </customizedue_type>
                                    -->
                                </types>
                            </customize>
                        </groups>
                    </custom>
                </options>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now i get the error "Invalid block type: Pi_Customize_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option".  But my file is stored at: "app/code/local/Pi/Customize/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php".  I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I found the error, i typed

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <class_to_override>
            my_class
        </class_to_override>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

but it has to be:

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <class_to_override>my_class</class_to_override>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```